# How to print all columns in a datareader

Tags: c#, ado.net, datareader

Using c# how do I print all columns in a datareader.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728170/system-data-common-dbdatareader/2728203#2728203

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This method will return an enumerable list of column names when passed a datareader:

```
static List<string> GetDataReaderColumnNames(IDataReader rdr)
{
    var columnNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
        columnNames.Add(rdr.GetName(i));
    return columnNames;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

To add some value to the answers, I included a possible extension method to return the column names for a given `DataReader`.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames(this IDataReader reader)
{
    for(int i=0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++)
        yield return reader.GetName(i);
}
```

Comment: I love extension methods,i feel like injecting into and exposing that behaviour.. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int j = 0; j < x.VisibleFieldCount; j++)
            Console.WriteLine(x.GetName(j));
```